# Invalid JSON when calling Node 8.10 Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cognito

I am using lambda with cognito to write to dynamoDB after a successful login.

Node 8.10 has a different layout with the promise and `asycn/await`. the `callback(null, event)` return is not working for my. Anyone now how to solve the problem of `Invalid lambda function output : Invalid JSON` with node 8.10.

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
//AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});
// Create DynamoDB document client
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.myHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    console.log ("Authentication successful");
    console.log ("Trigger function =", event.triggerSource);
    console.log ("User pool = ", event.userPoolId);
    console.log ("App client ID = ", event.callerContext.clientId);
    console.log ("User ID = ", event.userName);

    const params = {
        TableName: 'xxxx',
        Item: {
                'userId': event.userName,
                'systemUpdateDate': new Date().toJSON()
            }
        };

    let putItem = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Success", data);
        }
      });
    });

    const result = await putItem;
    console.log(result); 

    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    callback(null, event);
};
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the suggested Node 8 approach of `async/await` you should use the following approach to structuring your function:

```
async function handler(event) {
  const response = doSomethingAndReturnAJavascriptObject();
  return response;
}
```

You're getting that error because whatever you're returning isn't something that can be parsed as a JSON object.

Without seeing your code it's hard to debug further. I expect that you might accidentally not be `await`ing a `.promise()` version of a dynamo/cognito API call, which is causing you to return a Promise instead of a result.

n.b. you can still use the 'old' `callback()` method with Node 8 if you find it easier.

Comment: I just update my code, with the callback from old node.js and still is not working. Thanks for your help

Comment: Looking at your code, the problem looks like you're mixing your methods. Instead of `callback(null, event)` you should just `return event` (see my example is not using the callback function at all).